# Convert MMM YY to Date time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of dates in MMM YY format and would like to change to datetime

Is it possible to convert Dec 2016 for example to a date in python? So the output would be 01/12/2016?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(['Dec 2016'])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you asked for:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime('Dec 2016','%b %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(d)
```

Result:

```
01/12/2016
```

Comment: is there a need for `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: @LucasSeveryn the module `datetime` has the class we wanted named `datetime`. We can write less code if we import the class directly using `from datetime import datetime`, then `d = datetime.strptime` and so on

Answer (score 2):

Python has built-in module [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) that has [strtime and strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) functions that can convert formatted strings from/to datetime objects. Here is the example of these functions usage:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = 'Dec 2016'

print(datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(s, '%b %Y'), '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Output:

`'01/12/2016'`

---

According to `strftime()` and `strptime()` format codes:

- `%b` is Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
- `%d, %m, %Y` is day-month-year in a zero-padded format

Note that `%b` depends on locale! If you have non-US locale, names will be differ!

> `%b` - Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
>
> Jan, Feb, …, Dec (en_US);
>
> Jan, Feb, …, Dez (de_DE)